# Why are some linux commands not executable in Citrus like PWD

Tags: citrus-framework

I am connecting to Linux server using SFTP protocol using citrus FTP component. the following  command that was provide in the documentation was executing fine.

```
<send endpoint="ftpClient">
  <message>
    <payload>
      <ftp:command>
        <ftp:signal>MKD</ftp:signal>
        <ftp:arguments>test</ftp:arguments>
      </ftp:command>
    </payload>
  </message>
</send>
```

but when I provide another command like PWD as shown below

```
<send endpoint="ftpClient">
      <message>
        <payload>
          <ftp:command>
            <ftp:signal>PWD</ftp:signal>
            <ftp:arguments></ftp:arguments>
          </ftp:command>
        </payload>
      </message>
    </send>
```

I am getting error. but when i execute the above command using SSH protocol the command was executing fine

```
<send endpoint="sftpClient">
  <message>
    <payload>
      <ftp:command>
        <ftp:signal>pwd</ftp:signal>
        <ftp:arguments></ftp:arguments>
      </ftp:command>
    </payload>
  </message>
</send>
```

I am unable to figure out the problem and another thing is how execute two commands in a sequence using citrus ftp component for example ex: I want to move to a particular path and have see the size of files in that path for this we have to use "CD" command first and next we have "ls -l" how can I achive this using citrus.
  Here is the stack trace of the error

```
 TEST FAILED ssh_connection_Test <com.consol.citrus.samples.todolist> Nested exception is: 
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Failed to read ftp XML object from source
    at com.consol.citrus.ftp.message.FtpMarshaller.unmarshal(FtpMarshaller.java:120)
    at com.consol.citrus.ftp.message.FtpMessage.getCommand(FtpMessage.java:429)
    at com.consol.citrus.ftp.message.FtpMessage.getPayload(FtpMessage.java:384)
    at com.consol.citrus.ftp.client.FtpClient.send(FtpClient.java:108)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.SendMessageAction.doExecute(SendMessageAction.java:125)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:234)
    at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.doExecute(TestCase.java:153)
    at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42)
    at com.consol.citrus.Citrus.run(Citrus.java:403)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.invokeTestMethod(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:124)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:108)
    at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 37; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'PWD' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[OPEN, ABOR, ACCT, ALLO, APPE, CDUP, CWD, DELE, EPRT, EPSV, FEAT, HELP, LIST, MDTM, MFMT, MKD, MLSD, MLST, MODE, NLST, NOOP, PASS, PASV, PORT, PWD, QUIT, REIN, REST, RETR, RMD, RNFR, RNTO, SITE, SMNT, STAT, STOR, STOU, STRU, SYST, TYPE, USER]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:909)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:782)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:751)
    at com.consol.citrus.ftp.message.FtpMarshaller.unmarshal(FtpMarshaller.java:95)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: You say you get some error when sending the PWD signal. which kind of error? can you please provide some more error information?

Comment: @ChristophDeppisch added error content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error information you are giving is not related to the PWD signal. It fails because you send the signal `ls -ltr` which is not a supported signal when using the FTP client.

In case you want to list the files with FTP on the server you need to use the `LIST` signal.

Please do not mix up SSH and FTP commands and signals. Of course you can also open a SSH session and fire up the list files command with `ls`. But then you need to use the Citrus SSH client.

Comment: even for PWD signal I am getting the same error. added error trace in question.

Comment: and one thing how to send two  commands at once for example  want to move to a particular path and have see the size of files in that path for this we have to use "CD" command first and next we have "LIST" how can I achive this using citrus.

Comment: the test case XML is loaded as a whole file and therefore the error is raised as soon as you have an invalid signal in one of your actions.

Comment: LIST signal is able to hold an argument. This optional argument is the folder path that is used as change directory instruction. In addition to that there is a CWD signal (change working directory) that can be used to navigate to a folder on the server. The LIST signal without any argument uses the current working directory.